# UITabBarController shouldAutorotate doesn't call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created UITabBarController App. The App is three tabbar items (test1,test2,test3). test1 and test2 tabbar items selected go to splitviewcontroller(master,detail). test3 item selected go to viewcontroller in landscape mode. test3 item now show the page portrait only and but doesn't call shouldAutorotate mehod.

Below is my sample code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: have you overrided allowed orientations in info.plist?

Comment: any sample codes or steps.